# system requirements for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

My team is currently using VS2005 with the following development PCs that are a few years old: XP, Pentium D 2.8GHz, 2GB RAM.

My gut tells me that this is going to be poor hardware for VS2010 development. I am not running VS2010 beta but I am running Blend 3 beta and the performance is bad.

Can you point me to anything that I can show my boss to convince him to buy 6 new machines for my team?

Edit below after initial answer from Jon:

I should have added that my boss wants to upgrade current machines with new hard-drives so I am trying to use this opportunity to take a look forward and see if a HD upgrade is really worth it. This HD upgrade would not just be simple installation of 2nd drive but would replace current drive and would involve backup/restore or reinstallation headaches. There would be the added benefit of 64bit development too, something that we have been talking about.

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000666.html

Comment: Don't choke your developers with bad machines. Some simple math: You say "team" so I assume 4 people for math's sake, at $80/hr. If a new PC saves each 5 minutes/hr, you get more than $1000/week back in ongoing increased productivity. Get them some badass systems with i7, 6GB RAM and large decent displays. You won't regret it. And the ROI is evident.

Comment: My gut tells that those PCs are bad even for VS2005. ^^

Comment: @Alex, Assuming they are developing for 32bit what would >3.5Gb of RAM do?

Cheap upgrade is probably a SSD for the Visual studio install and the source code.

Comment: http://www.pcrequirements.net/en/softwares/microsoft-visual-studio-2010-system-requirements/

Answer (score 6):

Betas typically *are* bad in terms of performance. I know that [MS is working hard to improve the performance of VS2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/ricom/archive/2009/05/31/visual-studio-2010-performance-part-1-startup.aspx).

However, I have the beta running on my Samsung NC-10 netbook, so it does *work* on low spec machines.

Do you already find yourself frequently waiting for your machine to catch up? If so, that's the reason to give your manager: you'll be more efficient *now* with a new machine. If not, wait until VS2010 is out and you actually have it installed (will you even upgrade immediately?) - then *if* it's too slow, you can show that to your manager at that point.

Speculatively requesting an upgrade doesn't sound like a good idea to me.

Comment: It think it sucks on my Q6600. You are so patient.

Comment: I'm running VS 2010 on my HP tx2 tablet.  That's where I do all my dev't @home.

Answer (score 2):

Given that those Pentium-Ds are [dual](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819116253) [core](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819116213) processors, I'd suggest:

- maxing out the RAM
- Windows 7 x64
- separate faster HDDs

Those CPUs, while not at the top of the list, are decently powerful. They should handle today's workload of VS2005/2008 without much problems.

It's likely back to the RAM and probably HDD speeds. I know you didn't mention HDD at all, but consider  <strike>2 drives (OS and data)</strike> [an SSD drive instead](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/10/the-state-of-solid-state-hard-drives.html).

I realize this isn't a direct answer to your question of how to convince your boss to kick out the money, but if that doesn't work, perhaps this will help in terms of getting more performance.

Answer (score 1):

Even though I'm late a little, I guess I need to add that MS is really working hard to improve the performance of VS2010, but they aren't successful here. Using WPF slowed VS 2010 down a lot.

My experience shows that VS2010 has the only drawback, it's slow. Therefore, the developer machine should be based on Nehalem processor core at least and possess 4Gb memory.

Anyway VS2005 is not the best choice. VS2008 is much more mature.