# VS2010 Minimum RAM requirement

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-xp, requirements

I have 512 RAM, would i be able to run VS2010?

Comment: Check out answer on superuser:
http://superuser.com/questions/169403/what-are-the-minimum-and-recommended-requirements-to-run-visiual-studio-2010

Comment: yes you can--at least express--not sure about pro

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to settle with Visual Studio 2008. I run it with 512MB and with Windows XP SP2, also if you try to use Visual Studio 2010 your PC isn't going to explode.

Answer (score 1):

i doubt if you'll run windows never mind vs2010... in a word 'no'

jim

[edit] -product minimum ram: 1 GB (32 Bit) or 2 GB (64 Bit) RAM (Add 512 MB if running in a virtual machine)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/professional

Hardware Requirements

- Computer that has a 1.6GHz or faster processor
- 1 GB (32 Bit) or 2 GB (64 Bit) RAM (Add 512 MB if running in a virtual machine)
- 3GB of available hard disk space
- 5400 RPM hard disk drive
- DirectX 9 capable video card running at 1024 x 768 or higher-resolution display
- DVD-ROM Drive

Comment: It will probably run with lower specs, just not very well (if at all). To OP: Buy more RAM.

Answer (score 1):

from http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/professional,

> Software Requirements 1 GB (32 Bit) or
>   2 GB (64 Bit) RAM (Add 512 MB if
>   running in a virtual machine)

Personally I wouldn't run it on anything less than 2Gb. See also [system requirements for Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212419/system-requirements-for-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 1):

I am running VS2010 Express on a circa 2003 - P4 2.0ghz Laptop with a broken DVD drive and **512 RAM** and it works fine for the basics... though my integrated graphics card does not even support shaders.  My OS is Windows XP and I don't run anything else simultaneously though.  Overall not bad though.

Answer (score 0):

Being realistic this is going to be fairly unpleasant, if indeed possible. (Any modern MS operating system won't like 512MB, irrespective of what you want to run on it.)

That said, you can download the trial version (good for 90 days) at: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/download so you might as well suck it and see.

Answer (score 0):

The VS developers told me that they are targeting to a machine with 2Gb. 512Mb is not enough in any scenario. My machine with 4 Gb is not enough fast to develop comfortably.