# System Requirement for VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a laptop machine with below configuration:

1. Core 2 Duo @ 1.4 GHz
2. 4GB RAM
3. 320GB HardDrive
4. Windows 7

Whether this is sufficient for installing VS 2010? The speed of processor is 1.4GHz, but in Microsoft website they have given minimum of 1.6GHz processor speed. Can anyone tell from their experience?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will most likely install, however I would expect it will run slow. Depends on what sort of work you are doing. Small console apps would be OK but I doubt full blown WPF/Silverlight apps would be speedy. Also, if your connecting to a local SQL instance.. etc (could pull an increased overhead).

Sum Up.

Will install.
Work will be tedious.

Another SO post for reference [VS 2010 Requirments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212419/system-requirements-for-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: I would be working on WPF apps with SQL Server 2008. Will it work be sluggish?

Comment: It will work I would think, it would more than likely be sluggish, yes. Put it another way, im using VS2010, Win7, WPF and SQL 08 on a single PC and I have 8GB ram and dual core and sometimes its sluggish for me, so with your spec I would this it would be more often than not.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is the way that VS2010 uses WPF; you might find that large files behave a little jerkily in the text editor, but I don't think it'll be un-usable.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried VS2010, but I do have VS2008 + SQL Server Express installed on a netbook with a few years old Atom CPU and 2 GB of RAM, and it works fine though it's obviously a bit slow. So I'd assume that you'll have no problems since even if the requirements for VS2010 are higher, your laptop is much higher spec than that netbook.

Answer (score 0):

Will work. but might have some performace issues on Editor / Designer. I had a machine with almost similar configuration. used it for silverlight developement. I always has  problem in the design preview of the XAML file. - it gets loaded after some time then expected time.